# How do I get the module recipe.pipe?

Tags: python, module, pipe, recipe

I'm working with an older python file and not sure where the module recipe.pipe comes from. I've installed recipe but don't see anywhere in the documentation having pipe supported. I know this file has worked in the past, but I've reinstalled my system since then. I went ahead and installed pipe just seeing if it may work, but again no luck.

Example

```
import random
import recipe, recipe.pipe, recipe.rcp
from scorch.api.oauth import OAuth


tvbrecipes = recipe.RecipeManager('scorch')

r = recipe.pipe.Pipe(
items=[
    tvbrecipes.files.selectrandom(
        number_of_files=3
    ),
    tvbrecipes.video.transformations.crop(
        duration=random.randint(15, 45)
    ),
    tvbrecipes.video.effects.blend(
        opacity=0.7
    ),
    tvbrecipes.video.addaudio(
        audio=tvbrecipes.files.selectrandom(
            number_of_files=1

        ).cook('scorch/audio')
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example, including imports and a complete line of code?

Comment: updated with a better example. Not perfect.

Comment: What is the error you get when you run this?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recipe.pipe'